# how to decode string of html encoded with JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG

Tags: php, json

I have html which encoded by php `json_encode` with json constant

using `json_encode( $data, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG )`

**After & before `json_encode` / `json_decode`**

```
{"agent_designation":"Agent","agent_desc":"\u003Cp\u003EAhmed Khan is a commercial consultant, a B.School MBA with flair of consulting businesses. With insightful perception of end user concerns to methodical compliance in consulting Investor groups, his analytical perspective & proactive approach gave significant recognition. His transparency of information and numbers has gained him virtual clients internationally. He has an unchallenging advantage, in consulting business expansion clients conveying value from concept to completion. His consultation justifies a propertyu2019s relevance, while offering holistic solutions from cost to return on investments.\u003C\/p\u003E","agent_img":"\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/09\/Ahmed-Khan-31.jpg","agent_linkedin":"","agent_phone":""}
```

`$data` contains below html , it can be html with single quotes double quotes slashes or sometimes just a simple text.

```
<p>Ahmed Khan is a commercial consultant, a B.School MBA with flair of consulting businesses. With insightful perception of end user concerns to methodical compliance in consulting Investor groups, his analytical perspective & proactive approach gave significant recognition. His transparency of information and numbers has gained him virtual clients internationally. He has an unchallenging advantage, in consulting business expansion clients conveying value from concept to completion. His consultation justifies a propertyu2019s relevance, while offering holistic solutions from cost to return on investments.</p>
```

> Issue comes up when rendering this encoded html it shows
>   (`u003Cpu003E`) these types of characters.

Render with `json_decode`

```
        $agent_info = @json_decode( $data );
        echo '<pre>';print_r($agent_info);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
u003Cpu003EAhmed Khan is a commercial consultant, a B.School MBA with flair of consulting businesses. With insightful perception of end user concerns to methodical compliance in consulting Investor groups, his analytical perspective & proactive approach gave significant recognition. His transparency of information and numbers has gained him virtual clients internationally. He has an unchallenging advantage, in consulting business expansion clients conveying value from concept to completion. His consultation justifies a propertyu2019s relevance, while offering holistic solutions from cost to return on investments.u003C/pu003E
```

Comment: Show us a concrete JSON sample **right after** `json_encode` and **right before** `json_decode`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce any issues: https://3v4l.org/Q5NKL.

Comment: My gut reaction would be that you're mistreating backslashes at some stage and are removing the ``\`` from `\u003C`. Obviously I can't see where or how that would happen...

Comment: i dont know why this issue not occuring with your link, but i m using php 5.4 with linux server

Comment: Side note: `@` basically means "if there is an error please don't tell me about it so I can waste my time guessing" ;-P

Comment: @deceze can you please let me know where i m mistreating backslashes ? what m i doing wrong when encoding this

Comment: Again, I don't know. Does the code in my link copy-and-pasted to your server work as is?

Comment: There are also 2 much ignored json function called `json_last_error_msg();` and `json_last_error();` that might throw some light on you issue. So you can actually get an idea of the error _rather than just ignoring them with the @_

Answer (score -1):

When using JSON encode in data attributes, the norm is to not escape using JSON encode options but rather the standard mechanism for escaping for HTML attributes. In PHP that might be something such as htmlspecialchars or htmlspecialentities with the appropriate options for the HTML context.

When using JSON encode for embedding data in javascript you should only require JSON_HEX_TAG.

Don't quote me on that though as there may be scenarios or aspects that are left out. Browsers have a habit of having quirks that allow bipassing certain constraints. On the other hand, I don't think arbitrary escaping just in case is justified.

You can pass JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to output raw UTF8 rather than escaped. A few parsers object to this though. You should check what the standard has to say about it.